# How did they solve this quadratic?

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$H = \{z : z \in \mathbb{C}^*, \ \ \left\lvert z + \frac1z \right\rvert = a \}$$
>   Find the minimum and maximum value of $|z|$ such that $z \in H$

---

$$a^2 = \left\lvert z + \frac1z \right\rvert^2 = \left(z + \frac1z\right)\left(\overline z + \frac1{\overline z} \right) = |z|^2 + {z^2 + \overline z^2 \over |z|^2} +
{1 \over |z|^2} =   {|z|^4 - |z|^2(2) + (z + \overline z)^2 + 1 \over |z|^2 }$$

Hence, 
$$|z|^4 - |z|^2 \cdot(a^2 + 2) + 1 = -(z + \overline z)^2 \le 0$$

Thus,

$$|z|^2 \in \left[{a^2 + 2 - \sqrt{a^4 + 4a^2}\over 2},  {a^2 + 2 + \sqrt{a^4 + 4a^2}\over 2}\right]  \tag{3}$$

$$|z| \in \left[{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}\over 2},  {a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}\over 2}\right] \tag{4}$$

---

- How did we get from (3) to (4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward: square the limits for $|z|$ (as in (4))  to arrive at the limits for $|z|^2$ (as in (3)).

All steps for the left limit:

You need to establish $\sqrt {a^2 + 2 - \sqrt{a^4 + 4a^2}\over 2} = {-a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}\over 2}$. Squaring this translates into

$${a^2 + 2 - \sqrt{a^4 + 4a^2}\over 2} = ({-a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}\over 2})^2 = {a^2 -2 a \sqrt{a^2 + 4} + a^2 + 4\over 4} = {a^2 + 2 - \sqrt{a^4 + 4a^2}\over 2}$$

Done.

Likewise for the right limit.

Comment: How come I know the limits of $|z|$ in the first place ?

Comment: I explained in the answer.

Comment: I am a bit salty about this answer.

Comment: From dxiv's answer I see what you mean - sorry, that wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplification follows from the more general [radical denesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Denesting_nested_radicals) technique:

$$
\sqrt{u \pm \sqrt{v}} = \sqrt{\frac{u+w}{2}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{u-w}{2}} \quad\;\;\text{where}\;\; w^2 = u^2-v
$$

In the case here, $u=a^2+2, v=a^4+4a^2, w^2=(a^2+2)^2-(a^4+4a)=4\,$, then:

$$
\sqrt{{a^2 + 2 \pm \sqrt{a^4 + 4a^2}\over 2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2+4}{2}} \pm \frac{\sqrt{a^2}}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4} \pm a}{2}
$$

Comment: This was really useful. Thank you.